# Slick Slider JS + Fixed Header Overlap Issue- Only in Chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, slick.js

I am using [Slick](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) JQuery plugin for a carousel.

On the website that I added it to, I have a fixed header with a fixed drop-down menu.
When I added the Slick carousel, the drop-down menu is overlapped (only in Chrome).
The menu links are still clickable; they are just not visible.

JSFiddle: [here](https://jsfiddle.net/h8151xtf/)

In the actual website, not only is the drop down not visible above the carousel, but it is also behind all other elements above the carousel, but below the header.
The drop-downs that are too short to be cut off by the carousel are shown above all other elements:

JSFiddle: [here](https://jsfiddle.net/h8151xtf/1/)

When I add an `unslick` function to remove the carousel, the menu is able to overlap again, so I believe that it's something that the Slick plugin is doing that I'm not able to find:

JSFiddle: [here](https://jsfiddle.net/h8151xtf/2/)

Has anyone run into anything similar to this?  I haven't been able to find which elements are causing this issue.

---

---

**Edit:** I was able to find which elements it was, and fix the issue.  It turns out it was some CSS that doesn't seem to be used for the functionality that I need.

Loaded CSS file had the following:

```
.slick-slider .slick-track,
.slick-slider .slick-list
{
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
       -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
         -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
            transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
```

When I added this to my CSS file in the JSFiddle, it works:

```
.slick-slider .slick-track,
.slick-slider .slick-list
{
    transform: none;
}
```

JSFiddle: [here](https://jsfiddle.net/h8151xtf/3/)

I didn't put this as an answer because I don't understand what caused the issue, but I did want to post in case this is needed by others.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding  `header{z-index: 100;}` ??
I had a similar issue and I fixed it with that.

Comment: Yeah, I have a z-index of 10000 in the header-fixed.  I tried adding that to few other elements, but no luck.